# Image set to fit 'grandparent' but hidden inside 'parent'

Tags: html, css, image, size

I have a bit complicated problem,

I want IMAGE to set full size to DIV, but to be hidden to another DIV inside..

I'll give it my best to explain:

```css
#grandParent {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

#parent {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#child {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandParent">
  <div id="parent">
    <img id="child" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Made changes ^^

Thanks in adv :)

Comment: what is the point if the image hidden? Have you tried to set your parent and image width:100%?

Comment: So you want your image to be the size if your `grandParent` element, but not viewable, right?

Comment: cause i want to play with the width of the parent but the image will stay at the size of the grandparent//

Comment: @JackStoller yes

Comment: Could you set the width of the `img` tag to the same width as the `grandParent` element?

Comment: @JackStoller I set the `img` to `absolut` and the `grandparent` to `relative`, but when i set the `parent` to `overflow:hidden`, it doesnt affect on the `img`..

Comment: @OmerGilboa Check my answer to see the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
.grandParent {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
img {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

EDIT: Maybe I have a better idea.

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/rileyjsumner/pen/YjaLKX)

Comment: It seemed as if you were asking to hide the image. Your explanation is unclear what you want.

Comment: OK, the `img` need to be full size to `grandparent`, but hidden inside `parent` but the `img` need to be visible. now lets say that the `grandparent` is `width:100px;` and the `parent` is `width:50px;` ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#grandParent {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}

#parent {
    width: 25vw;
    height: 25vw;
}

#parent::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="grandParent">
  <div id="parent">
      <img id="child" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg/220px-Liliumbulbiferumflowertop.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

I removed the `opacity: 0` on the image and put `overflow: hidden` on the parent element. I used the `vw` to get the percent of the screen. Try expanding the snippet to full screen and resizing the window.

### Edit

I used a pseudo element and I think is working right now.

Comment: if i set the `img` to `opacity:0;`, i could not put an image at all, i want the image to be in the size of the `grandparent` but set to be hidden inside the `parent` but still visible !

Comment: @OmerGilboa Sorry I completely missed that. So in this example, only half the img would show right?

Comment: yes,  say that the `grandparent` is `width:100px;` and the `parent` is `width:50px;`

Comment: @OmerGilboa Try using the `vw` or `vh` as I used in my newest answer.

Comment: check the edit i did to my post ^^ i think you will understand better what im trying to do ..

Comment: @OmerGilboa Edited, sorry about all this